# How to verify if array has empty values or digits in it

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I want to check whether an array has a value in it or it is empty. The case below has some empty values.

```
 a = [1,2,3,"","","",7]
```

I have code as below, but it is not working.

```
a.each do |f|
  if [f].empty?
    puts "array is empty"
  else
    puts f
  end
end
```

Comment: Maria, `[f]` will never be empty, as it will always contain one element of `a`, even if that element is an empty string (or, say, `nil`, if `a` constained a value `nil`).  I think what you want is `if f.is_a? String and f.empty?..`. If you want to know if `a` contains any empty strings, you can do this: `a.select { |e| e.is_a? String and e.empty? }.any?`.

Comment: @vgoff makes two suggestions which represent improvements to what I offered in my earlier comment: using `any?` rather than `select` (any dropping `any?` at the end) and using the more general `respond_to` in place of `is_a? String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,"","","",7]

puts a.empty?
puts a.any? { |e| e.respond_to?(:empty?) && e.empty? }
```

The array simply isn't empty, so `a.empty?` will return false.

However, we can check each of the elements to find out if `any?` are empty.  We do have to be careful to check for those things that respond to `empty?` as a method.  This will answer the question if any are.  Otherwise we will end up with an `NoMethodError`, which would happen on calling `1.empty?` for example.

Code that is similar to yours:

```
a.each do |e|
  if e.respond_to?(:empty?) && e.empty? 
    puts "Nothing here."
  else
    puts e
  end
end
```

Comment: How to use it inside loop as i want to find if a particular value is empty or not...your code checks for whole array and prints the results?

Comment: You wouldn't have to use a loop if you want to check a specific element.  If you wanted to check `a[3]` for instance,  you could pull that element by index and check.  Which code are you asking about though, the `any?` code may check for only the first that returns true, and then exit from the block, with no need to continue, as you have the answer.. If one is true, then the question "any?" is answered.  I provided code to mirror your given code that was not working, in the second block of code.

Comment: Good answer, Victor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to check if an array element is `blank or nil`.

```
a = [1,2,3,"","","",7]
a.any?{|i| puts i.to_s.empty? || i.nil?} #=> returns true/false
a.any?{|i| puts (i.to_s.empty? || i.to_s.nil?) ? "Empty":"Not Empty"} #=> prints empty/not empty
```

Comment: I know that this is not code review.  But the `Enumerable#any?` method returns true if any of the results in the block return true.  With the puts in there, it is guaranteed that any? will always return false.  You may as well use the `each` method with your block, semantically.  You are relying on a side effect, rather than the actual result of the `any?` method.  In any case, your comment that it 'returns true/false' is misleading.

Comment: @vgoff: Your comments are very valid. Much appreciated